# Date difference from Noda Time is correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, nodatime, localtime

```
DateTime dtStart = new DateTime(2015,7,28);
LocalDate ldtStart = LocalDate.FromDateTime(dtStart);

DateTime dtEnd = new DateTime(2017, 2, 1);
LocalDate ldtEnd = LocalDate.FromDateTime(dtEnd);

Period period = Period.Between(ldtStart, ldtEnd, PeriodUnits.YearMonthDay);
```

**Result for above:**
period.Years -> 1
period.Months -> 6
period.Days -> 4

As you can see the difference i got from Noda Time library.
But i get different result for https://www.easycalculation.com/date-day/age-calculator.php
**Result for above link:**
1 years, 6 months, and 1 days

*Start Date*: 28th July 2015
*End Date*: 1st Feb 2017

Can someone please tell me that the result i got from noda time plugin is more accurate then the link I provided?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.  It's about counting the number of days between the 28th of a month and the 1st of the next month.  This does not require a computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"More accurate" requires a specification of how you want to compute the difference. There's no single right answer here. As [documented](http://nodatime.org/2.0.x/userguide/arithmetic), Noda Time works element-wise. So if you add 1 year, 6 months and 4 days to 28th July 2015 you get:

- Adding 1 year: 28th July 2016
- Adding 6 months: 28th January 2017
- Adding 4 days: 1st February 2017

The code used for the site is [available on the site itself](https://www.easycalculation.com/code-c-program-age-calculator.html). It looks like that's taking a rather more naïve approach.

In particular, if you ask it how old someone born on January 31st 2017 is on February 1st 2017, they'll say they're -2 days old. I don't think that's right...

Comment: Thanks @jon Skeet for explaining the logic used by NodeTime and validating the result and for suggestion to using this plugin. Ya that link seems to be less accurate, guess i'll use NodeTime for calculating difference between work experience. One final question: Is there a way to add multiple periods from different date difference to final period?

Comment: @PratikGhag I'm not sure what you mean, but I suggest you ask a new question with a clear example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'll try to figure this one out on my own. If i got stuck i'll ask it. :)

Comment: Got it. http://nodatime.org/2.0.x/userguide/arithmetic here you can find addition of multiple periods objects. Search "Adding a Period".

Answer (score 1):

From *28th July 2015* to *1st August 2015* is 4 days and from *1st August 2015* to *1st Feb 2017* is exactly one and a half year.

NodaTime shows you correct information. You also could check with this [link](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=28&m1=07&y1=2015&d2=01&m2=02&y2=2017.).

You could try to change in [your link](https://www.easycalculation.com/date-day/age-calculator.php)  date from *28th July 2015* to *29th July 2015* or *30th July 2015* and you will see invalid input.

Comment: Thanks @Max Mokrousov, according to your explaination I am concluding NodaTime is more accurate than https://www.easycalculation.com/date-day/age-calculator.php.